# Source for the menorah represents the wisdoms of the world?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, behaalotcha-parsha

This blog post claims that the Meiri along with other Rishonim taught that the Menorah ,mentioned in Behalotecha represents the 7 wisdoms of the world.

Quoted here:

*The Meiri and other Rishonim say that the Menorah’s  seven lights represent the seven wisdoms. The Rishonim classify them as follows:*

*1) Tevunah, the ability to understand and draw conclusions.
2) The knowledge of nature - in subjects like chemistry and physics.
3) The knowledge of the soul – or as Rav Aharon puts it, the study of psychology.
4) The knowledge of biology
5) Music
6) Metaphysics… (philosophy)  and
7) The knowledge of Torah …. which is the most significant branch.*

The blogs fails to cite the exact source of the Meiri and other Rishonim who purportedly make this assertion, where might I find this Meiri?

http://haemtza.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-seven-branches-of-wisdom.html?m=1

Comment: I think that the first one as תבונה is a mistake for תכונה (astronomy)

Comment: Probably the Meiri part is https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/28/9/1/mg/60 and the blogger is combining multiple things together.

Comment: REFERENCE: Klein Dictionary
תְּכוּנָה ᴵᴵᴵ f.n. MH astronomy. [For the etymology of the word see תְּכוּנָה ᴵ. The meaning ‘astronomy’ is derived from תִּכֵּן in the sentence שָׁמַיִם בַּזֶּרֶת תִּכֵּן (Is. 40:12), ‘He meted out heaven with the span’.]